# Multiple SessionFactories' sessions together

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am trying to implement a sharded Hibernate logic. All Databases have same table called MyTable which is mapped to MyClass through Hibernate POJO.

```
public class SessionFactoryList {
List<SessionFactory> factories;
int minShard;
int maxShard;
// getters and setters here.
}
```

In my Dao implementation, I have a method getAll which is following -

```
public class MyClassDao {
@Autowired // through Spring
private SessionFactoryList list;

List<MyClass> getAll() {
List<MyClass> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
for(SessionFactory s : list.getFactories()) {
    Criteria c = s.getCurrentSession.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
    outputList.addAll(c.list());
}
return outputList;
}
```

Here is my test for the corresponding getAll implementation -

```
public class MyClassTest {
 @Autowired
 SessionFactoryList list;
 @Autowired
 MyClassDao myClassDao;

 @Test
 void getAllTest() {
  Session session1 = list.getFactories.get(0).getCurrentSession();
  session1.beginTransaction();
  session1.save(new MyClass(// some parameters here));
  Session session2 = list.getFactories.get(1).getCurrentSession();
  session2.beginTransaction();
  session2.save(new MyClass(// some parameters here));

  //Set up done.
  assert myClassDao.getAll().size() == 2

 }
}
```

I am using HSQL in-memory database for the test cases.
I have verified that DB connections are correctly setup, but the Assert statement is failing.

'getAll' method of MyClassDao is returning 3 rows. MyClass object inserted in SessionFactory1's session is getting duplicated.

Is there anything I am missing out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The 2 sessionFactory configurations which I used for the test had same Database URL. Hence the same database was queried twice which caused the duplicates.